# Yocto: Bitbake does not start menuconfig

Tags: gnome-terminal, yocto

Im trying to enable a Kernel-module in my Yocto image, as I have done this already before with an older installation where this works properly.

This is the command I'm running:

> $ bitbake linux-variscite -c menuconfig

And then I've got this error:

> $ ERROR: Unable to spawn terminal auto: ...
>   ... (Translated to English) The option "--disable-factory" is not supported in this Version of gnome-terminal.

AFAIK yocto tries with "disable-factory" to open a new instance of a gnome-terminal.

My Host-System is a Debian Jessie with Mate-Desktop environment.
I've also tried to run bitbake from a KDE-Konsole, bit then I've get the same error, so I assume yocto calls "gnome-terminal" direct.

What can I do? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 4):

Last time I had to do this I overrode the default gnome-terminal, which I don't have, with xterm. Assuming you have installed xterm then edit your `local.conf` file, eg with

```
echo 'OE_TERMINAL = "xterm"' >>conf/local.conf
```

Comment: Works for me on Exception: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied;
ERROR: Function failed: do_menuconfig

Answer (score 1):

I faced a very close problem with Yocto. 
I use to configure and compile Linux kernels with a Yocto tool-chain through a **ssh X forwarded session**. The computer on which I run Yocto is installed with a regular **Ubuntu-16.04**. If I use the menuconfig command directly on this computer everything is going well and the menuconfig window comes up into a gnome-terminal.

```
    bitbake -c menuconfig -f virtual/kernel
```

But as soon as I use the same command line into a ssh session the same gnome-terminal never shows up:

> ERROR: Unable to spawn terminal auto: Execution of
>   '.../linux/0.1-r0/temp/run.do_terminal.13867'
>   failed with exit code 1: Option "-t" is no longer supported in this
>   version of gnome-terminal.
>
> Error constructing proxy for
>   org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Could not connect:
>   Connection refused

My solution was to edit the terminal.py file into the poky directory as :

sources/poky/meta/lib/oe/terminal.py
and add the **dbus-lanch**.

```
 line 56 : command = 'dbus-launch gnome-terminal -t "{title}" --disable-factory -x {command}'
```